# How to make Jqplot Bar chart point labels vertical align.?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am making a graph where I need little help. (I have googled so much but can't succeed thats why asking. - If possible duplicate  I apologize.) [image]

My Code:

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot('distance_graph', data.distance, {
                // The "seriesDefaults" option is an options object that will
                // be applied to all series in the chart.
                seriesDefaults:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {fillToZero: false},
                    pointLabels: { show: true },
                },
                // Custom labels for the series are specified with the "label"
                // option on the series option.  Here a series option object
                // is specified for each series.

                // Show the legend and put it outside the grid, but inside the
                // plot container, shrinking the grid to accomodate the legend.
                // A value of "outside" would not shrink the grid and allow
                // the legend to overflow the container.
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    placement: 'outsideGrid'
                },
                axes: {
                    // Use a category axis on the x axis and use our custom ticks.
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        label: 'Date',
                        ticks: ticks,
                        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {
                            angle: -30
                        }
                    },
                    // Pad the y axis just a little so bars can get close to, but
                    // not touch, the grid boundaries.  1.2 is the default padding.
                    yaxis: {
                        label: 'Distance Travelled',
                        pad: 1.05,
                        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {
                          labelPosition:'middle'
                        },
                        min:min_val,
                        max:max_val     
                    }
                }
            });
        plot2.legend.labels = data.device;
        plot2.replot( { resetAxes: false } );
```

and How can I remove 0 values also, Because I am converting this chart to multiple Item's chart. This is currently One Item's Chart.. So How to remove 0 labels also...

Comment: Thank you DDK, I understand now. I will keep it in mind.. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on these examples: [point-labels](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php), you can modify the display of point labels using `.jqplot-point-label` class in your CSS. Therefore, you can use CSS `transform` property to rotate the text as described here: [how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-to-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser)

To remove labels for 0 values, you need to provide a set of labels with zeros changed to empty strings. You can use this custom set like this:

```
pointLabels: {
    show: true,
    labels: customSetOfLabels
},
```

Here's [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/dVuD2/) - however, it looks like jqPlot blocks requests from jsfiddle so sometimes the scripts don't load. You can either try locally or visit the [jqPlot demo page](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php) and the jsfiddle in one browser window so the scripts are loaded from cache.

I used a JavaScript array [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create the custom set of labels like this:

```
function removeZeros(x){
    return x===0 ? '' : x;
}
var line1 = [14, 32, 41, 44, 0, 40];
var line1Labels = line1.map(removeZeros);
```

Please note that `map()` might not work in all browsers so you might want to iterate over the array using a for loop instead.

Comment: Thank You for answer. This vertical labels works fine in Firefox. I haven't tested right now in other ones. I have used pointLabels: { show: true,hideZeros:true, fillToZero: false },

Comment: Thank You for answer. This vertical labels works fine in Firefox. I haven't tested right now in other ones. I have used       pointLabels: { hideZeros:true} for Hiding zero, Everything else works fine. Thankx. Can u please help me with some legends formating ? Legends on charts are display over on chart though i have done placement:'outsideGrid'..

Comment: Is it also posible to give legend table a scrollable?, so looks gui good.[Links and hints are accepted].